# How do I exclusively lock a file on Windows?

Tags: windows, go, locking

I want to lock file exclusively on Windows environment, but `syscall.Flock` isn't supported by Windows.
Is there any way to implement it?

I tried [this article](http://ikarishinjieva.github.io/tachikoma-blog/post/2014-03-20-go-file-lock/)'s method however it doesn't work (`syscall.Syscall6` raises "Access is denied." error).

Comment: In Windows, you lock a file when you open it.  Look at the documentation for whichever Go function you are using to open the file, perhaps there will be an option to request exclusive access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows c++ api could help you. The [LockFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365202%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [LockFileEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365203%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) functions seem enough to help.